Shared conda environments stopped working for me (and ONLY for me)
Background:
I have a server shared by a small group of people. We have a shared conda installation and shared conda cache, so everybody can install what is needed for him/her while avoiding lots of duplicate packages being cached in many different user accounts (mostly because some bioinformatic packages come with HUGE databases that are unfortunately installed in the conda path by default).
With this setup everybody can create private environments (stored in their personal .conda subdirectory in their own home-folder) and use public ones (stored in /opt/miniconda/envs). But only privileged users can create/modify public environments
The Problem:
The above setup worked fine until recently conda seems to be broken for me (and ONLY for me). Several public environments are non-functional for me, but working for all others. Mostly it is a python-module that cannot be found in my case. However everybody is using the exact same environment, and show the same exact python-path.
An example of this problem is what happens when I run gtdbtk from the following global environment /opt/conda/miniconda/envs/gtdbtk/ (created specifically to run only the bioinformatic tool gtdbtk):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/miniconda/envs/gtdbtk/bin/gtdbtk", line 6, in <module>
    from gtdbtk.__main__ import main
  File "/opt/conda/miniconda/envs/gtdbtk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtdbtk/__main__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from gtdbtk.files.stage_logger import StageLogger
  File "/opt/conda/miniconda/envs/gtdbtk/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gtdbtk/files/stage_logger.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pydantic import BaseModel
  File "pydantic/__init__.py", line 2, in init pydantic.__init__
  File "pydantic/dataclasses.py", line 48, in init pydantic.dataclasses

ImportError: cannot import name dataclass_transform

-->This problem ONLY occurs for me. Every other user can just activate and use this environment. Also I was able to use it in the past also. I really do not know what happened to change that...
Even when removing these environments, cleaning the conda cache and recreating them as my own private environments still leads to broken environments (but only in my case, not for other users).
Any Ideas on what could be wrong for me (or with me)?
